# Find all complex solutions of $\sin(z)=1-i$.

Tags: complex-numbers

For this question I tried to use this identity:

$$\sin(z)= \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

and let $\sin(z)= \dfrac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})}{2i}=1-i$,
then
 $e^{iz}-e^{-iz}-(2i+2)=0$;

multiply both sides of this equation by $e^{iz}$,and let $w=e^{iz}$,

$w^2-(2i+2)w-1=0$,

I got

$w=(1+i)\pm\sqrt{1+2i}$,

what can I do next?

Comment: Write $z =x+iy$ in $w=e^{iz}$ $\rightarrow$ $e^{-y} = |w| $

Comment: $e^{a+ib} = e^ae^{ib}$

Comment: i have found this here $$\arcsin \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {5}-1/2 \right) -i\ln  \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {5}
+1/2+\sqrt { \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {5}+1/2 \right) ^{2}-1} \right) 
$$

Comment: You simply need to solve $$u^2=1+2i$$ then $$e^{iz}=1+i+u$$ To find $u$, use $u=\xi+i\eta$ and find $(\xi,\eta)$ by solving $$\xi^2-\eta^2=\xi\eta=1$$ To deduce $z$, use $z=x+iy$ then $$e^x=|1+i+u|\qquad e^{iy}=\frac{1+i+u}{|1+i+u|}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the complex root formulas, one is
$$
\sqrt z=\sqrt{|z|}\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}
$$
which would give here
$$
\sqrt{1+2i}=\sqrt[4]{5}\frac{\sqrt5+1+2i}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}=\frac{(1+\sqrt5)+2i}{\sqrt{2+2\sqrt5}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the identity $\arcsin (w) = -i \ln \left(iw + \sqrt{1 - w^2}\right)$ to obtain the solutions as follows,

\begin{align}
z&= \arcsin (1-i ) \\
&= \arcsin (\sqrt2e^{-i\frac\pi4}) \\
& = -i \ln \left(\sqrt2e^{i\frac{\pi}4} \pm \sqrt[4]5e^{\frac{i }2 \arcsin\frac2{\sqrt5} }\right) \\
&= -i \ln \left(1\pm \phi^{1/2}+ i \left( 1\pm \ \phi^{-1/2}\right) \right), \>\>\> \phi=\frac{\sqrt5+1}2\\
&= -i \ln \left(r_{\pm}e^{\pm i \theta+i2\pi k}\right) ,\>\>\>r_{\pm}^2 =\sqrt5+2\pm2\sqrt{\sqrt5+2},\>\tan\theta =\phi^{-1/2}\\
 &= 2\pi k\pm \theta -i \ln r_{\pm} \\
&=2\pi k\pm \arctan\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}2}-\frac i2\ln \left(\sqrt5+2\pm 2\sqrt{\sqrt5+2}\right)
\end{align}